# Jquery- backslash character

Tags: javascript, replace, escaping

I am having a problem trying to replace the backslash character from a string:

```
var g = myReadString;
g = g.replace("\", "\\\\");
```

it is giving an error of unrecognized character.

How could a simple `\` be replaced  with four `\\\\`?

I would appreciate any help,
thanks.
Pandy

Answer (score 9):

The `\‍` is the begin of an escape sequence. If you mean to write `\‍` literally, you need to write `\\` that is an escape sequence as well and will be interpreted as a single `\‍`. So if you want to replace one `\‍` by four `\\\\`, you need to write this:

```
g.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\")
```

But this will only replace the first occurrence of a single `\‍`. To do a global replace you need to use a regular expression with the global match modifier:

```
g.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\\\\\")
```

Comment: I think that OP actually wants to replace a single backslash with *four* literal backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
g = g.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

I think that's what you're looking for. Let me know if not.

Comment: Hello my friend, it doesn't work. it doesn't replace the character.
For example, I would want:
IN: "myvalue\assa" (1 backslash)
OUT: "myvalue\\\\assa"

Comment: @Samuel Beckett In that case you must actually replace with eight(!) backslashes (i.e., four escaped backslashes).

Answer (score 0):

The backslash also serves as an escaping character.  You can find a list of characters on this page... http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/special_characters.htm

So, in order to search for, or replace a backslash, you have to escape the backslash.  I actually just ran your code, and it doesn't work, as the backslash is escaping the first quote.  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you want to replace each single backslash with a double, you will need something like this.

```
var g = myReadString;
g = g.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!, well the solution that works is:
 g = g.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");

Comment: No problem at all! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

In *general* make sure to always escape correctly.

In your first argument for `replace()` you intend to pass a string containing `\` but it ends up as `",`  (quote-comma-space)! This is because you're actually escaping the "closing" quote on the string:

```
g = g.replace("\", "\\\\");
              ^    ^
              s    e
              t    n
              a    d
              r
              t
```

Now the first argument is the string quote-comma-space. The rest gives a syntax error!

What you wanted:

```
g = g.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");
              ^  ^  ^        ^
              s  e  s        e
              t  n  t        n
              a  d  a        d
              r     r
              t     t
```

First argument: The string `\`
Second argument: The string `\\\\`